# Finding the line number of first occurrence of a text in bash script

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I need to find out what is the line number of first occurrence of a given search string that should be in the start of a line in a text file and store it in a variable in my bash script. For example I want to find the first occurrence of "c":

```
abc
bde
cddefefef // this is the line that I need its line number
Casdasd // C here is capital, I dont need it
azczxczxc
b223r23r2fe
Cssdfsdfsdf
dccccdcdcCCDcdccCCC
eCCCCCC
```

I came up with this but as you see there are big problems

```
   trimLineNum=$(cat "${varFileLog}" | grep -m1 -n "c")
   echo "c is at line #"${trimLineNum}
```

The output will be:

```
c is at line #1:abc
```

Problems:

1. So obviously it matches the first line, because there is a "c" in the line.
2. The output will also include the content of the line as well! I want it to be just the number of the line

what should I change to fix those problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `grep` about your “that should be in the start of a line” constraint, by anchoring the match to the start of a line with `^`:

```
trimLineNum=$(grep -m1 -n -- '^c' "${varFileLog}")
```

Then post-process `grep`’s output to only keep the line number:

```
trimLineNum=$(grep -m1 -n -- '^c' "${varFileLog}")
trimLineNum="${trimLineNum%%:*}"
```

Note that `-m` is a GNU extension (and with GNU `grep`, you need `--` even though `^c` doesn't start with `--` in case `$varFileLog` itself might start with `-` as GNU `grep` accepts options even after non-option arguments). Standardly, you could pipe the output to `head -n 1` instead.

If there's no match, the first command will return false/failure while the second will always return true unless you enable the `pipefail` option as supported by several shells including `bash`.

Answer (score 8):

With POSIX `sed`, you suppress normal output with the `-n` option, then for the line starting with `c` (pattern `^c`), print the line number with `=` and `q`uit:

```
sed -n '/^c/{=;q;}'
```

With GNU `sed`, you can use the `Q` command to quit without output and simplify to

```
sed '/^c/!d;=;Q'
```

Comment: You could simplify to `sed '/^c/=;d'` (no `-n` option used). Of course, that will run the whole file tru sed.

Comment: @QuartzCristal This will work for the example file, but the description says to only print the line number of the first occurence, so it would require an additional `|head -n 1` or `|sed 1q`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That is why I said that *will run the whole file tru sed.*

Answer (score 7):

Several solutions exist

### with AWK

```
awk '/^c/ { print NR; exit}' "${varFileLog}"
```

- `/^c/`: matches the line starting with `c`
- `print NR`: prints the record (line) number
- `exit` : does not continue processing

As I like `awk`, this is my preferred solution

### with grep + filtering

```
grep -n '^c' "${varFileLog}" | head -n1 | sed 's/:.*//'
```

- `'^c'`: matches the line starting with `c`
- `head -1` : only displays first line from grep's results
- `sed 's/:.*//'` : removes anything after the `:`

`sed 's/:.*//'` and `cut -d: -f1` have the same effect in that case

#### about performance

This may be slower than Stephen's solution:

```
grep -m1 -n '^c' "${varFileLog}" | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: upvoted for the awk answer. I wouldn't bother with the rest as they're all inferior to that one in terms of conciseness and/or portability and/or efficiency.

Comment: Why pass grep output to cut? If the result need to be saved in a variable i think is better to use parameters expansion: `lineno=$(grep -m1 -n -- '^c' "${varFileLog}");lineno="${lineno%%:*}"`

Comment: Why pipe to `tail`? The OP need the first so it should be `head`.
Also note that `... | head -1 | sed '...'` can be done with just `sed` as well : `... | sed '1s/:.*//;q'`

Comment: @DanieleGrassini that is correct, thank you, I corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

grep can print the line number of a match with `-n` or `--line-number` so you can use that.

```
$ cat sample.txt | grep '^c' --line-number
3:cddefefef // this is the line that I need its line number
10:cat // added to illustrate getting the first occurence vs. all
```

The problem then reduces to:

- Get the first line only
- Pull out just the number without the matched text

You can do the first one with `head` and the second with `cut`:

```
$ cat sample.txt | grep '^c' --line-number | head -n 1 | cut -d':' -f1
3
```

In your example output, you have some extra text - I'm not sure if this is important to you or not. However, when you have a number on STDOUT, adding some string prefix to this is a straightforward task, and I'll leave that one up to you.

Comment: Note that in `grep '^c' --line-number`, POSIX compliant implementations of `grep` are *required* to print the lines of the `--line-number` file that start with `c`. GNU `grep` only does that if called with `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in its environment. You should put options before non-option arguments. POSIXly: `<sample.txt grep -n '^c'` (also removing the UUOC and replacing the `--line-number` GNUism with the standard and portable `-n`).

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i; ++$i; say "c starts line $i" and last if m/^c/;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i; ++$i; say "c starts line $i" and last if (.index("c").defined && .index("c") == 0);'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i; ++$i; say "c starts line $i" and last if .starts-with("c");'
```

Outputs:

```
c starts line 3
```

Raku's `-ne` (linewise non-autoprinting) command line flags are used. To get the line number a `state` variable `$i`is initialized once, then incremented for every line read. Where a beginning-of-line "c" is identified (either by regex, or `index`, or `starts-with`), the string `"c starts line $i"` is interpolated and output (`say`).

Note: the low-precedence conditional `as last` is added to each example above. Remove this conditional to return all matching line numbers, e.g.:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'state $i; ++$i; say "c starts line $i" if m/^c/;'  file
c starts line 3
c starts line 10
```

---

Addendum: Thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72810990/7270649), here's a quick way to get the first zero-indexed line number starting with "c" using Raku's `first` routine:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'say lines.first(* ~~ / ^ c /):k;' file
2

#OR

~$ perl6 -e 'say lines.first(*.starts-with("c")):k;'  file
2
```

---

Sample Input:

```
abc
bde
cddefefef // this is the line that I need its line number
Casdasd // C here is capital, I dont need it
azczxczxc
b223r23r2fe
Cssdfsdfsdf
dccccdcdcCCDcdccCCC
eCCCCCC
cddefefef // this is the line that I need its line number (again)
```

https://raku.org